# Why do I need an extension to log into the network?

Tags: networking, windows-server-2012

Anywhere else in the building I just need to use my username and password to log into the server, but on my laptop, for some reason I need to user the server name as well, like so;

> SERVER_NAME\User 
>   Password

There are several other laptops in the network, *but this only occurs on my laptop.* Why?

Comment: Why post a bounty when an accepted answer exists? The post is also missing information about the differences between your laptop and other computers, such as domain membership and network.

Comment: @harrymc It was a mistake, but too late I had already posted it. The original answer I was looking for was not in the *answer*, but in the *comments*, but I didn't realise until after I posted the bounty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add or promote your laptop to domain controller and check the reported issue

**Step One**

Starting at the desktop, click the Start button. Find Computer and right-click the menu item. A submenu will appear, and you will select Properties

**Step Two**

The System Properties window will appear. Under the Computer Name, Domain, and Workgroup settings. you will see a shield icon with Change Settings. Click this text link.

**Step Three**

The System Properties dialog box will appear. Under the Computer Name, tab click the Change… button.

**Step Four**

A Computer Name/Domain Changes dialog box will appear. Under the Member of section, select the Domain radio button. Input your domain into the field. Your domain name will be supplied by your supervisor or network administrator.

Important! Before adding a system to the domain, make sure there is no other system with that same name.

**Step Five**

Another dialog box will appear immediately, prompting you to log in using your domain/network credentials. Input your username and password and click the OK button.

**Step Six**

If you managed to input all your credentials correctly, and you achieve connectivity to the domain controller, you will be welcomed to the xxxxxxxxxx domain.

**Step Seven**

You will be prompted to restart your system. Click the OK button.

**Step Eight**

You will be prompted again to restart the computer from the System Properties dialog box near the bottom of the box with Changes will take effect after you restart this computer. Click the Close button.

**Step Nine**

You will at last be prompted to restart your system again after closing the prior dialog box. Click the Restart Now button to complete the process.

**Step Ten**

After restarting, you will be welcomed back to Windows with the user logon screen. You will notice that the default login account is a local machine account “MachineName\Username”. Just below the password field, click the “Switch User” button. At the next screen click the “Other User” button (presumably with no display picture). This will automatically put you on the domain. Just sign in with your normal domain credentials beyond this point.

Note: To log back in to the machine account, type in .\Username (Where username is the name of your local account, such as the default Administrator: .\Administrator). Input your password and log in to a local off-domain account.

Hope this helps!

Comment: It was all going good up until step 4. the "Domain" option has been greyed out...

Comment: Also, I am doing this as the Administrator.

Comment: What OS is your laptop? You must be running at least a "Professional" such as Win 7 Pro or above, Win 8 Pro or above etc. "Home", "Home Premium" and "Basic" versions cannot join a domain so you will have to put up with entering your credentials in that manner if it's not Pro.

Comment: @BigChris Sorry for the late response, didn't realise you had responded. I believe I am just running the standard version (Basic?) of Windows 8 (I can't see any other information about it).

Answer (score 0):

Your problem seems to be that your Windows version is Home/Basic and so cannot join the office domain.
This is an artificial limitation by Microsoft whose purpose is to motivate the upgrade to Pro
or Ultimate.

My research of the issue indicates that Home/Basic cannot join a domain because a registry entry blocks the required protocol. It might not work any more with Server 2012, but the old remedy was in the laptop to regedit to `HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa` and create a DWORD item named [LmCompatibilityLevel](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc960646.aspx) with the value of 1. Reboot is required.

Comment: Unfortunately all I get is a webpage that cannot be displayed.

Comment: What steps do you take to get to that webpage? [Joining a domain](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/connect-computer-domain#1TC=windows-7) is not via the browser.

Comment: I typed it into the address bar in the windows explorer...

Comment: Additionally, as I said in the comments in the previous question, I am unable to Join a Domain, or set up a Network ID, because both of these options are inaccessible to me.

Comment: These options are grayed-out, but I think there are ways to get around them. You could try the discontinued [X-Setup Pro](http://www.majorgeeks.com/files/details/x_setup_pro.html) as described [here](http://vowe.net/archives/001639.html) (for XP but may still be valid), or the more recent method described in [this article](http://winsupersite.com/article/windowsserver2012/windows-server-2012-essentials-connecting-windows-7-8-home-versions-144442).